# Scaling an image OSX Swift

Tags: swift, image, macos, cocoa, nsimage

Im currently trying to scale an image using swift. This ***shouldnt*** be a difficult task, since i've implemented a scaling solution in C# in 30 mins - however, i've been stuck for 2 days now.

I've tried googling/crawling through stack posts but to no avail. The two main solutions i have seen people use are:

[A function written in Swift to resize an NSImage proportionately](https://gist.github.com/eiskalteschatten/dac3190fce5d38fdd3c944b45a4ca469#file-imageresizer-swift-L1)

and

[resizeNSImage.swift](https://gist.github.com/ericdke/1387b3b89938b6cf3732#file-resizensimage-swift-L1)

[An Obj C Implementation of the above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223739/ios-to-mac-graphiccontext-explanation-conversion)

So i would prefer to use the most efficient/least cpu intensive solution, which according to my research is option 2. Due to option 2 using `NSImage.lockfocus()` and `NSImage.unlockFocus`, the image will scale fine on non-retina Macs, but double the scaling size on retina macs. I know this is due to the pixel density of Retina macs, and is to be expected, but i need a scaling solution that ignores HiDPI specifications and just performs a normal scale operation.

This led me to do more research into option 1. It seems like a sound function, however it literally doesnt scale the input image, and then doubles the filesize as i save the returned image (presumably due to pixel density). I found another stack post with someone else having the exact same problem as i am, using the exact same implementation ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831389/change-resolution-and-size-of-image-with-cocoa-osx-swift-no-mobile-apps)). Of the two suggested answers, the first one doesnt work, and the second is the other implementation i've been trying to use.

If people could post *Swift*-ified answers, as opposed to Obj C, i'd appreciate it very much!

**EDIT:**
Here's a copy of my implementation of the first solution - I've divided it into 2 functions:

```
func getSizeProportions(oWidth: CGFloat, oHeight: CGFloat) -> NSSize {

    var ratio:Float = 0.0
    let imageWidth = Float(oWidth)
    let imageHeight = Float(oHeight)

    var maxWidth = Float(0)
    var maxHeight = Float(600)

    if ( maxWidth == 0 ) {
      maxWidth = imageWidth
    }

    if(maxHeight == 0) {
      maxHeight = imageHeight
    }

    // Get ratio (landscape or portrait)
    if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
      // Landscape
      ratio = maxWidth / imageWidth;
    }
    else {
      // Portrait
      ratio = maxHeight / imageHeight;
    }

    // Calculate new size based on the ratio
    let newWidth = imageWidth * ratio
    let newHeight = imageHeight * ratio

    return NSMakeSize(CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight))
}


func resizeImage(image:NSImage) -> NSImage {
    print("original: ", image.size.width, image.size.height )

    // Cast the NSImage to a CGImage
    var imageRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    let imageRef = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: &imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)

    // Create a new NSSize object with the newly calculated size
    let newSize = NSSize(width: CGFloat(450), height: CGFloat(600))
    //let newSize = getSizeProportions(oWidth: CGFloat(image.size.width), oHeight: CGFloat(image.size.height))

    // Create NSImage from the CGImage using the new size
    let imageWithNewSize = NSImage(cgImage: imageRef!, size: newSize)

    print("scaled: ", imageWithNewSize.size.width, imageWithNewSize.size.height )

    return NSImage(data: imageWithNewSize.tiffRepresentation!)!
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As pointed out by Zneak: i need to save the returned image to disk - Using both implementations, my save function writes the file to disk successfully. Although i dont think my save function could be screwing with my current resizing implementation, i've attached it anyways just in case:

```
func saveAction(image: NSImage, url: URL) {

    if let tiffdata = image.tiffRepresentation,
    let bitmaprep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffdata) {

    let props = [NSImageCompressionFactor: Appearance.imageCompressionFactor]
    if let bitmapData = NSBitmapImageRep.representationOfImageReps(in: [bitmaprep], using: .JPEG, properties: props) {

        let path: NSString = "~/Desktop/out.jpg"
        let resolvedPath = path.expandingTildeInPath

        try! bitmapData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: resolvedPath), options: [])

        print("Your image has been saved to \(resolvedPath)")
    }
}
```

Comment: "Should" or "shouldn't"? Trivial means easy. Also, are you doing this for the purpose of showing it on screen or writing it back to disk or something else? Scaling to a bigger or a smaller size?

Comment: edited the OP :)

Comment: And im Scaling down to write back to the disk

Comment: What is the purpose of converting `CGFloat` to `Float` and then back to `CGFloat`? And you don't need parentheses around `if` expressions in Swift.

Comment: Totally forgot to change that for the post... Initially they were all floats, but i've changed so many different parts trying to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else experiencing this problem - I ended up spending countless hours trying to find a way to do this, and ended up just getting the scaling factor of the screen (1 for normal macs, 2 for retina)... The code looks like this:

```
func getScaleFactor() -> CGFloat {
    return NSScreen.main()!.backingScaleFactor
}
```

Then once you have the scale factor you either scale  normally or half the dimensions for retina:

```
if (scaleFactor == 2) {
    //halve size proportions for saving on Retina Macs
    return NSMakeSize(CGFloat(oWidth*ratio)/2, CGFloat(oHeight*ratio)/2)
} else {
    return NSMakeSize(CGFloat(oWidth*ratio), CGFloat(oHeight*ratio))
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking for a specific scale factor, you should instead divide by it: `CGFloat(oWidth*ratio)/scaleFactor`. This way your code will continue to work correctly should Apple introduce devices/modes where the backing scale factor is some other value. But *do* check for 0 first!

Comment: Would be a nice way of doing it - For the time being though i was happy to get it working :P